# How can I take a few chars and print it as a one word

Tags: c, char, printf, scanf, conversion-specifier

I need help in C, I need to build a software that takes from the user (input) 3 chars and then print it as a word.
For example the user enters:

```
A
B
C
```

then the software should print ABC.

I tried doing it on this method:

```
printf("%c %c %c",char1,char2,char3);
```

but the issue is that it printed it like:

```
A,B,C
```

If anyone has any idea how can I print it as a one word it would be awesome.
Thanks.

Comment: Hmm... there's no way `printf("%c %c %c",char1,char2,char3)` produces `A,B,C` as output...

Comment: Your code prints `A B C` If you don't want the spaces just do `printf("%c%c%c",char1,char2,char3);`

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to confirm the output of your current attempt is as you say.

Comment: Thanks User 4386427 I tried it without spaces and now it's working as I wanted

Answer (score 1):

Some methods:

```
int main(void)
{
    char a = 'A', b = 'B', c = 'C';
    char d[] = {'D','E','F'};
    char e[4];

    //print as one word - separate variables
    printf("%c%c%c\n", a, b, c);

    //print as one word - array of chars (not the C string)
    for(size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(d); i++)
    {
        printf("%c", d[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    //make string and print it
    e[0] = a;
    e[1] = b;
    e[2] = c;
    e[3] = 0;

    printf("%s\n", e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Write

```
scanf(" %c %c %c", &char1, &char2, &char3);
printf("%c%c%c\n",char1,char2,char3);
```

Comment: Thanks Vlad from Moscow, yeah I tried it without spaces and now it's working as I wanted.
Thank you guys so much!

Comment: @TheWitherStone: Please be sure to mark this as the accepted answer by checking the checkbox next to the answer. That will mark this question as having been resolved—and also reward Vlad from Moscow for the effort.